# Computer Vision: How to obtain what percentage of image contains a specific texture?

Tags: python, computer-vision, google-cloud-platform, vision

I am building a app to see the progress of deforestation. Over time i would like to take a satellite image from a location and see what percentage of that image contains forest.

I have attempted google's vision API, it does not have this functionality.

Is this something that can be done in OpenCV or must I do this from scratch with semantic segmentation or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

So far I could see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate) there doesn't seem to be any pattern/texture recognition for the API. My belief is that you could try to do a [dominant color recognition](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#DominantColorsAnnotation). if your image data has enough data of differentiable colors,  I think you should be able to get an acceptable analysis.

PD: Having some experience with satellital imagery processing, as additional info, I can comment that the usual way to find out the status of the land for plants, forest and general crop development and health is though color analysis.

Nonetheless, Satellite/drone images are mostly multispectral and several UV bands are extensively used as biomass behaves very different with season/health/development status with the combination of visible and UV electromagnetic bands.

Comment: @Nicky Feller was any answer useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look at the satellite image recognition Kaggle competitions? There are a lot of discussions as well as available scripts for tasks similar to yours:
Links: https://www.kaggle.com/c/dstl-satellite-imagery-feature-detection
Example script: https://www.kaggle.com/arpandhatt/satellite-image-classification